# Better way using an IDisposable object many times in a class

Tags: c#, idisposable

Say that we have a class with name A that implements the `IDisposable` interface. So when we
use it, we write:

```
using(classA cA = new classA())
{

}
```

Let that we wantuse classA, which is actually in my case a class in a module holding business logic, in many methods of another class. Is there any way to avoid using the above coding in all of them?

In other words, is there a better way to use classA than the following?

```
class B
{

    // properties

    // constructors

    // methods

    public void methodA()
    {
        using(classA cA = new classA())
        {
            // code goes here
        }
    }

    public void methodB()
    {
        using(classA cA = new classA())
        {
            // code goes here
        }
    }

    public void methodC()
    {
        using(classA cA = new classA())
        {
            // code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make class `B` implement `IDisposable`.

Create an instance of `A` in `B`'s constructor (or create it lazily on first use), store it in a field and dispose it in class `B`'s `Dispose` method.

Answer (score 2):

It really does depend on how short lived you need ClassA to be.

One alternative would be to make ClassB implement IDisposable

```
class B : IDisposable {

    private classA cA;

    public B() {
      cA = new classA();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        if (cA != null) {
           cA.Dispose();
           cA = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But you would then need to wrap all calls to classB with a using so I'm not sure what you'd gain.